# Even after removing GUI from Kali, I can see the terminal in GUI

Tags: kali-linux

I have removed GUI from Kali in VM, but I am still able to see the terminal in UI form, but not able to resize it.

I have used the commands from here: https://linuxconfig.org/kali-linux-without-gui

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove xfce4* kali-desktop-xfce libxfce4*
```

How can I remove the UI completely and get only terminal? Also it would be helpful to have option for having multiple terminal tabs or windows.

Comment: does booting into `multi-user` target (`step 1` https://linuxconfig.org/kali-linux-without-gui) logs you into `cli` only interface?

Answer (score 0):

On [the page you linked](https://linuxconfig.org/kali-linux-without-gui) steps 1 and 2 (before that step 3 you mentioned in your question, namely `sudo apt purge --autoremove xfce4* kali-desktop-xfce libxfce4*`) describe the *soft-approach* to *request* the system/init to handle the requested default target:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user
```

This will request the init of your kali-install to set the boot-target to command-line-interface with full network/multiuser-capabilities.

I am mentioning this because (i can only assume that) you might have misinterpreted the numbered list, namely **Step 2 / Option B**:

> "To re-enable the GUI to start automatically upon system boot, change
> the systemd target to graphical"

... *While in text explicitly stating that this re-enables the GUI*, as ***needed*** for the process?

It is not, in fact it should have been described as *either/or*, not as a numbered list, which normally describes a sequence.

Anyhow, if indeed using **Step 1 / Option A**

> "The following Linux command will disable GUI on boot hence upon the
> reboot the system will boot into multi user target"

... aka `set-default` to `multi-user` does not do the trick, you can ***request more prominently*** by using:

`systemctl isolate multi-user.target`

This will turn the former ***request*** into a ***demand*** or to be frank, into a ***commandment***, hence it is considered dangerous. This is mentioned in the [man-page for systemctl](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html), stating:

> isolate UNIT
> Start the unit specified on the command line and its
> dependencies and stop all others, unless they have
> IgnoreOnIsolate=yes (see systemd.unit(5)). If a unit name
> with no extension is given, an extension of ".target" will be
> assumed.
>
> ```
>        This command is dangerous, since it will immediately stop
>        processes that are not enabled in the new target, possibly
>        including the graphical environment or terminal you are
>        currently using.
>
>        Note that this operation is allowed only on units where
>        AllowIsolate= is enabled. See systemd.unit(5) for details.
> ```

The alternative (in the orignal document presented as ***Step 2*** instead of ***Option B***) would be the vice-versa way to switch from CLI to GUI by utilizing:

`sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target`

Please **be aware** that the use of `systemctl isolate` ***enforces*** the use of the target you point it to.